# Error en conexión a bd de sql server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server

Buenas estoy intentando pasar todo el proyecto que tengo en mi laptop para la maquina del trabajo todo me funciona bien excepto la conexion a la bd de sql server lo unico que cambia con respecto a lo que tengo en la lapto es el nombre del servidor. Hice un debug y el error que en la conexion es este:

> ```
> ex = (org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException) 
> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC 
> Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se 
> pudo realizar la conexión TCP/IP al host (local), puerto 1433. Error: "null. 
> Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay una instancia de SQL Server 
> ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto y compruebe 
> que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando las conexiones TCP en el puerto.".
> ```

Este es el codigo donde se crea la conexion:

```
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSourceRecursosHum() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://(local);databaseName=RecursosHum;");
    //;integratedSecurity=true
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("sa");

    return dataSource;
}
```

Y aqui es donde hago la consulta a la bd:

```
  public Trabajador BuscarTrabajador(int id)
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Trabajador WHERE Trabajador.CodTrabajador="+id;
    List<Trabajador> list = null;
    try {
        list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Trabajador>() {
            public Trabajador mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
               return new Trabajador(rs.getInt("CodTrabajador"),rs.getString("CarnetI"), rs.getInt("NoExpediente"),rs.getString("Nombre"),rs.getString("Apellido1"),rs.getString("Apellido2"), rs.getString("Sexo"),rs.getInt("CodCargo"),rs.getInt("CodUnidad") );
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
        Logger.getLogger(TrabajadorDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list.get(0);
}
```

Comment: tienes que considerar que el nombre del servidor de base de datos que estás usando es "local", probablemente debas usar el nombre real de la instancia de SQL Server a la que te quieres conectar. Además revisar que en efecto haya una base de datos `RecursosHum` y que el usuario `sa` con password `sa` tenga permisos en esa base

Comment: Consulta, decis que lo único que cambio es el nombre del servidor pero en tu codigo seguis poniendo (Local) ¿esto es así? o tenes la bse instalada en otro server, en ese caso ¿sabes el nombre del server?
¿Probaste conectarte directamente al servidor nuevo por afuera de la aplicación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta linea está mal:

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://(local);databaseName=RecursosHum;");
```

El nombre del host es incorrecto. Probá con la siguiente linea:

```
String Connectionurl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=YourDBName;user=UserName;Password=YourPassword"
```

Exitos!